# Show edit notification at bottom of posts

Tags: feature-request, edits, live-refresh

When taking part on a question where comments are attempting to gather additional information, quite often the page scrolls down beyond the point where you see the "post edited, click to reload" banner and it's easily missed unless you notice all the contents jump down a few lines.

Could the banner be duplicated at the bottom of the post nearer the comments?  Or have one that appears across the top of the page, similar to the "new answers" banner when answering a question?

---

*If* the [currently being tested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258048/a-b-testing-the-sticky-vote-controls-give-your-feedback-please?cb=1) sticky voting controls are permanently implemented, another location for placing an indication of post-activity (editing, closing etc) could be below the Mark as favourite button.

Comment: This might be really confusing depending on the scroll height. What happens when you now scroll up and see both of them? This might seem strange. I would rather see something like [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242423/show-question-updates-in-the-page-title).

Comment: @ArtjomB. Yes - two banners may be confusing - that's why I had the thought of the fixed at top of screen banner.  Doesn't matter where you're scrolled to, the text could make it obvious that the question on the current page has been edited.

Answer (score 3):

I have had the same frustration a few times.

Although I'm not sure about the post simply having the message top and bottom on all posts, as it will be cluttered on smaller ones.

### Suggestions

1. Only duplicate the current (top) message to the bottom on posts of a
   certain height
2. Or another notification type which is obvious when on a long post
   and no matter where on the post you are - eg the border changing to
   light blue 2px (just example, for want of a better idea)
3. A small "tab" which appears at the edge of the post wherever on
   the post you are, stating "Edited". When clicked reloads the post.

With 3, the tab will be accessible no matter where on the post you are. It could also (perhaps) only activate when top of the post is off the screen (*and* an edit is made).
Which would avoid cluttering view on smaller posts which do not go off screen.

I'm in favour of 3.

Comment: Or change the background of the post slightly. No extra space is used up then.